# How can I find the location visited by all employees in this sql table?

Tags: mysql

I have a sql table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `location_visits` (
  `employee1_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `employee2_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `region_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`employee1_name`,`employee2_name`),
  CONSTRAINT `location_visits_fk1` FOREIGN KEY (`employee1_name`) REFERENCES `employees` (`employee_name`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `location_visits_fk2` FOREIGN KEY (`employee2_name`) REFERENCES `employees` (`employee_name`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
)
```

Employees go to places together in pairs, sort of like a buddy system. I want to find the region(s) that has been visited by all employees.

If it helps, I also have a table that lists all of my employees:

```
CREATE TABLE `employees` (
  `employee_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ('employee_name')
)
```

All these tables are loaded with data, of course. So, an example for data that would be valid for `location_visits` table is `(John, Chris, Maine), (John, Adam, New Hampshire), (Adam, Chris, Maine)`. In this scenario, the location visited by all employees `Adam, Chris, John` is `Maine`.

What kind of sql command would do this for me?

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the count of all distinct employees from each region and get the regions that have the total number of employees equal to the ones present in the employee table. Your query should look something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(employee1_name), region_name FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT employee1_name, region_name FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT employee1_name, region_name FROM location_visits
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT employee2_name, region_name FROM location_visits))
GROUP BY region_name
HAVING COUNT(employee1_name) =
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT employee_name) FROM employees);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```sql
SELECT employee1_name, employee2_name FROM location_visits WHERE region_name='Maine'
```